# Trying to understand specificity calculation in CSS

Tags: css-specificity

I am reading MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#understanding_the_cascade). They are explaining specificity in CSS. For `button:not(#mainBtn, .cta)`, specificity is given as 1-0-1. Since, there is one class involved here, I think the specificity should be 1-1-1. According to their explanation, `:not()` doesn't add to specificity itself but its parameters or nested rules do. So, can anybody explain, why the specificity is 1-0-1 and not 1-1-1 here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read carefully:
The negation (:not()), relational selector (:has()), the matches-any (:is()) pseudo-classes, and CSS nesting themselves don't add to specificity, but their parameters or nested rules do. **The specificity weight that each contributes to the specificity algorithm is the specificity weight of the selector in the parameter or nested rule with the greatest weight.**

Comment: So, `#mainBtn`  id has greater weight than `.cta` class. That means class weight is discarded and id weight is counted here. Is that right ?

Comment: yes, thats how I interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

The comma is used to separate rules and combine them without having to write them twice.
`button:not(#mainBtn, .cta)` is equivalent to this:

```
button:not(#mainBtn){...

button:not(.cta){...
```

It applies to either the id or the class, an element targeted by this rule doesn't need to have both the class and the id. Therefore, the specificity is 1-0-1.